# What is the set $2\mathbb{N}$ (and why is it not a subset of $\mathbb{N}$)?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Consider $f$ : $\mathbb{N}$ $\rightarrow$ $2\mathbb{N}$. Then $f$ is bijective and $\mathbb{N}$ is equivalent to $2\mathbb{N}$.

This is in my topology notes online. What is $2\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: It is the set of positive multiples of $2$.

Comment: Then why is it not a subset of N, if that is the case?

Comment: A common notation is that of $A$ is a set and $f$ a suitable function then $f(A) = \{ f(x) \}_{x \in A}$. Here $f(x) = 2x$.

Comment: It is a subset.

Comment: [A set is infinite if and only if it is equivalent to one of its proper subsets](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Infinite_Set_Equivalent_to_Proper_Subset)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the set of even integers $\{0, 2,4,6,\dots,2n,\dots\}$ (if your definition of $\mathbb{N}$ includes $0$; it is $2\mathbb{N} = \{2,4,6,\dots,2n,\dots\}$ otherwise).

It **is** a subset of $\mathbb{N}$: $2\mathbb{N}\subseteq \mathbb{N}$; actually, even a *strict* subset. But this doesn't prevent the bijection to exist. Basically, $\mathbb{N}$ is countably infinite, and therefore (pretty much by definition) of same "cardinality" as every other countably infinite set—including any infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$.